# ECMAScript not working for anonymous user

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have a code like below to get current web in my SharePoint 2013 portal project

```
var clientContext;
var website;
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', sharePointReady);
function sharePointReady() {
clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
website = clientContext.get_web();

clientContext.load(website);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSucceeded, onRequestFailed);
}
function onRequestSucceeded() {
    alert('URL of the website: ' + website.get_url());
}
function onRequestFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Error: ' + args.get_message());
}
```

When I log in to site everything works perfect. But when I open site with anonymous user web url not is not avaliable. Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SharePoint 2013 was introduced new permission level `Remote Interfaces Permission` that in particular prevents anonymous users from accessing CSOM libraries.

### How to enable CSOM for Anonymous Users

- Go to Central Administration
- Go to Manage Web Application
- Select your Web App
- Click on Authentication Providers in the ribbon
- Click zone "Default".
- Uncheck "Require Use Remote Interfaces Permission"

That check box decouples use of CSOM from the Use Remote Interfaces permission.  When checked, it simply means that the user must possess the Use Remote Interfaces permission which allows access to SOAP, Web DAV, the Client Object Model.

### References

- [Enable anonymous access for Javascript Client Object Model](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/e752b077-48d8-4d66-a5d8-60f34e9b285d/enable-anonymous-access-for-javascript-client-object-model?forum=sharepointdevelopment)
- [What Every Developer Needs to Know About SharePoint Apps, CSOM, and
  Anonymous Publishing Sites](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2013/10/24/what-every-developer-needs-to-know-about-sharepoint-apps-csom-and-anonymous-publishing-sites.aspx)

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem but I still get some values in display templates for Search Service. So, I can't get url of site